# Can text input height/width be styled to be the same with or without the DOCTYPE?

Tags: html, css, doctype

I do support for an older, large website that was written without the DOCTYPE being set. The test example below shows the discrepancies, but is there a way to make the sizes render identically using the same style sheet?

(WHY?: Adding the DOCTYPE to this site will have to be a gradual and carefully tested implementation for the several thousand pages of code, and before I get started I'm seeing if it's possible to avoid maintaining two separate CSS sheets).

[image: Browser rendering on Chrome]

Source Code (with doctype):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Untitled 1</title>
<style type="text/css">
input, div{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
input[type=text],input[type=password]{
    border:1px #AAAAAA solid;
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 3px;
}
</style>
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Too big with doctype" style="width:200px" onclick="alert(this.offsetHeight)">
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="height:24px;width:100px;background-color:#dddddd;">100 x 24px</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Too small without doctype" style="width:200px;height:22px" onclick="alert(this.offsetHeight)">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="height:24px;width:200px;background-color:#dddddd;">200 x 24px</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="height:24px;width:100px;background-color:silver;">100 x 24px</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="height:24px;width:200px;background-color:#dddddd;">200 x 24px</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

So to me it appears that without the doctype, the sizes of text inputs render exactly as you specify them. But with the doctype, it adds the border and any padding to the height or width. Can I get around this without creating a separate stylesheet?

Comment: Short answer: NO. `doctype` is what indicates to the browser which standard (or lack of as in quirksmode) to follow.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering! I was hoping to come across some sort of clever CSS trick, but I may be out of luck there.

Comment: Im not 100% sure, but i think that you could use a CSS reset sheet and use your doctype...http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing with? Consider adding adding a `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` rule, to include border/padding in the width on newer browsers (matching old-school IE behavior).

Comment: Perfect - that's fixes it! Adding box-sizing makes them the exact same either way. And for the record the above screenshot is with the latest version of Chrome... I also tested Safari, Firefox, and older versions of IE, and the results were very similar.